# Converter HTML em PDF - pdfsharp

Tags: html, c#, .net, angularjs

eu estou com uma outra dúvida agora, estou tentando utilizar PDFSharp HtmlRenderer, para gerar um pdf, para enviar por email.
Eu baixei o pacote nuget, e  função é assim:

```
 public static Byte[] PdfSharpConvert(String html)
    {
        Byte[] res = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var pdf = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
            pdf.Save(ms);
            res = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return res;
    }
```

O que acontece, todos os meus itens que eu preciso que seja gerado o PDF, é gerado em uma div no front. Queria passar essas informações do front para o back, para que seja gerado o PDF, é possível ??
Eu nem preciso necessariamente salvar este pdf, pode ser algo temporário, para enviar por email.
Estou meio perdida na biblioteca PDFSharp, estou lendo os documentos, porém estou é mais confusa rs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi, vi que você também está utilizando angularjs, então acredito que seja melhor gerar o pdf com o próprio angular e após isso enviar ele como arquivo já pronto para o BackEnd e assim salvar e enviar pelo email.

Utilize essas bibliotecas.

```
import * as jspdf from 'jspdf';  

import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
```

crie um botão ou algo parecido para copiar a div:

```
<input type="button" value="PDF" (click)="captureScreen()"/>
```

e após isso gere o PDF:

```
export class HtmltopdfComponent{  
  public captureScreen()  
  {  
     var data = document.getElementById('sua div para converter');  
     html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {  
     var imgWidth = 208;   
     var pageHeight = 295;    
     var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;  
     var heightLeft = imgHeight;  

     const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')  
     let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  
     var position = 0;  
     pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)  
     pdf.save('MYPdf.pdf'); // Generated PDF   
    });  
  }  
}
```

Comment: Eu fiz o teste aqui @Matheus, mas ele só sai uma folha, e vai ter casos que vai ter mais de uma folha, e também esta div estava com `style="display: none;"`, e ai retornava erro, eu tive que tirar para conseguir gerar, e mesmo assim não ficou da forma correta

Comment: Consegue postar um exemplo de como precisava e de como está saindo ?

Comment: Matheus conseegui fazer funcionar, mas não vou utilizar essa opção, rs obrigado.